# Is there a word that means "to throw to the garbage"?

Tags: word-request

I thought of *discarded* and *getting rid of*. But I wonder if there's a more specific word.

Example sentence:

> I searched for the soap, finally discovering that my girlfriend had __.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not exactly a single word, the phrasal verb [**to throw away**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/throw-away) is as specific as it can possibly get when describing a situation where you want to get rid of something that you no longer need. It strikes me as a little bit odd that you've never heard of this, rather basic, English expression before. I'm pretty sure you have, though. You just forgot.

Examples:

> Did you **throw** the papers **away**? Why did you do that? I still need them!
>
> I'm going to **throw away** all my broken toys. What do I have to keep all that junk for?
>
> I was looking for this soap everywhere, only to discover that my girlfriend had **thrown** it **away**.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of [**throw out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw%20out) (definition 1b):

> I searched for the soap, finally discovering that my girlfriend had **thrown it out**.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single term you may use ***[discard](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discard)*** though it sounds less colloquial than “throw away”:

> If you discard something, you get rid of it because you no longer want it or need it.

(Collins Dictionary)

- I searched for the soap, finally discovering that my girlfriend had discarded it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can express this:

1. to throw away
2. to trash
3. to dispose of
4. to dump
5. to scrap
6. Yes even, to discard

"To dump" and "to trash" are somewhat informal, though so long as you're not writing a thesis, you should be fine.

Comment: Another good informal one is "to toss".